# Sharing excel sheet

Tags: excel, file, file-sharing

I am getting trouble when sharing excel sheet via e-mail. I want certain people to see all the updates I make in my sheet.

When recipiant open it for a first time, he can view the changes I make. But after that, he can still open a sheet, but doesn't see any updates I make. How to fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You send them a one time copy by email, how do you expect it to be updated?

Publish it on a website then they download the latest version.

Or put it on a server and they download it.

Comment: Not a one time copy. It was saved in a wrong location... Your answer is worst then my question:DD

Comment: @Egis "Your answer is worst then my question" should be "Your answer is worse than my question"... Spelling errors matter. The two options I suggested will work - just because YOU don't like them...